# On hover of table cell text, make font size of element bigger while keeping the height of the table cell the same

Tags: html, css, hover, cell

when I hover on the text inside cell I want that text to get its size increased by 120%. But in my code the column and whole table moves when I hover on **marketplace** and **integrations** and **newsletter**.
I also tried many solutions but couldn't make it.

That is  :
When I hover on **MARKETPLACE** it should increase its font-size by 120%, it does it, but the problem is the column section moves, same thing happens in **integrations** and **newsletter**
It would be great if someone help me in this.

```css
#footer h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: -145px 0px 0px 150px;
}

#footer div table {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 800px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 0px 115px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#footer div table tr td {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 70%;
  position: relative;
}

#footer div table tr td a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  height: 220px;
  /* position: relative; */
}

#footer div table tr td a:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: red;
  font-size: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Overview</a></td>
        <td><a href="">About</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Contact</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Pricing</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Team</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Newsletter</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Marketplace</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Blog</a></td>
        <td><a href="">LinkedIn</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Features</a></td>
        <td><a href="">careers</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Integrations</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Prevent column resize: Use *table-layout: fixed;* for your table. The table columns will not resize automatically anymore. You may need to apply a width to each td in the first table row if you want to define the width for each column perfectly. This step will fix the hover issue for "newsletter".
2. Prevent row resize: Add *display: block;* or *display: inline-block* to your a-tags and a *height that is bigger than the scaled font height* (e.g. 30px). The height property that you have in your CSS only works for (inline-)block elements but a-tag is inline by default. Remove *position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 2px;*. This will fix the other issues.
3. Bonus: Optimize code

   - Remove all *position: relative;*.
   - Remove the *height from table*.
   - Move *transition: 0.5s;* from *a:hover* to *a*
   - Consider to simplify your CSS selectors (e.g. *#footer div table tr td* to *#footer td*

In the end your CSS code could look like this:

```
#footer h1 {
   font-size: 35px;
   margin: -145px 0px 0px 150px;
}

#footer table {
   color: black;
   text-align: left;
   width: 800px;
   margin: 0px 115px 0px 0px;
   font-size: 14px;
   table-layout: fixed; /* see 1. */
}

#footer td {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 70%;
}

#footer td a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   display: inline-block; /* see 2. */
   height: 30px; /* see 2. */
   transition: 0.5s;
}

#footer td a:hover {
   color: red;
   font-size: 120%;
}
```

Comment: thank you.  This works fine. But how do I align it vertically in cells

Comment: @ThusharP For *#footer td a* use *display: flex;* instead of *display: inline-block;* and *align-items: center;*

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `scale`, which since it's a paint time operation, doesn't affect the layout. However, transforms don't work on inline boxes, so we have to make the `a` element `inline-block`, and apply a translate so that the text stays left aligned. This needs to be half the increase in size, so for 120% scale, we need a 10% translate on the x-axis.

```css
#footer h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: -145px 0px 0px 150px;
}

#footer div table {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 800px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 0px 115px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#footer div table tr td {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 70%;
  position: relative;
}

#footer div table tr td a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#footer div table tr td a:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: red;
  scale: 120%;
  translate: 10%;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Overview</a></td>
        <td><a href="">About</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Contact</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Pricing</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Team</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Newsletter</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Marketplace</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Blog</a></td>
        <td><a href="">LinkedIn</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Features</a></td>
        <td><a href="">careers</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="">Integrations</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works fine.  But when I hover on it the text goes blur on this.